# Migrate site from local to local via a backup

Tags: migration, localhost, backup

I have a WordPress site installed locally on my computer. The project was almost finished. Today I turned on my computer but it no longer works (categorically refusing to turn on), the repairman told me it's hard drive problem but I managed to get the project files which was in this hard drive thanks to a file recovery box (I recovered the WordPress files which were in www).

Before that, I had made a backup of the project in Dropbox via the UpdraftPlus plugin.

Now I bought a new computer and would like to know if there is a way to get my project back and how.

I count on you if not I will lose two months of work. Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Check this out: https://updraftplus.com/faqs/how-do-i-migrate-to-a-new-site-location/  If you have an Updraft Back-Up you should just be able to rebuild the site using that.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to, but only if you have a copy of the database.

Simply place all the files in the Webroot of the new environment and import the database. If using a different database name / username / password make sure to change the info in your wp_config.php

Edit: you may also be able to use the updraft backup to restore it into a new installation

https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/plugins/restore-site

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I don't have the database copy so I'll try your second solution and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, he kinda put me on the right track

Answer (score 0):

I managed to recover my site, I did the following:
-Install a wamp version in my new computer (an identical version that I had in the old computer if not it does not work)
-Put the folders of my site that I recovered from the old hard drive to the new root (www)
-Put the Mysql data files (wamp64 /bin/MySql/MySql5.7.23/data) from the old computer to the new computer except the databases installed by WAMP by default: "mysql", "performance_schema" "sys" .
-On my new server, in the data folder, there is also an "ibdata1" file present. I renamed it "ibdata.bak", then paste the "ibdata1" that I previously copied from the old server.
Thanks for your help, he kinda put me on the right track